# Enum cant work properly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

I have

```
enum unit_type: [:Ad, :Survey]
```

in my model.

-But when I query

```
ViewsLog.where(:unit_type=>"Survey").count
```

It doesn't work properly

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "views_logs" WHERE "views_logs"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "views_logs"."unit_type" = $1  [["unit_type", 0]]
```

It still get `:unit_type => 0` data

Comment: Is `"Survey"` the same as `:Survey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `snake_case` (which is lowercase) identifiers in your enums:

```
enum unit_type: [:ad, :survey]
```

This is because ActiveRecord uses the key to map to scope methods and interrogators. And this not just violates the naming conventions but may lead to weirdness since Uppercase = Constant in Ruby. You can use this scope method to query:

```
ViewsLog.survey.count
```

If you for some reason need to write the where clause you should use a symbol and not a string for the enum identifier:

```
ViewsLog.where(unit_type: :survey).count
```

Comment: ViewsLog.where(unit_type: :survey).count not working

Comment: Care to elaborate on why its not working? If you read the [documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) this is exactly how you are supposed to query an enum column if the built in scopes don't fit your use case. But I don't see why you don't use `ViewsLog.survey.count` instead.